# Create sdk source package from specified android source revision

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

I want to debug some android internal api, but debugger points to wrong sdk source code lines.

I cloned frameworks/base/ project from [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-6.0.1_r17) revision but seems there is no script to create similar source package:
[image]

How to create source package from specified android source revision to use it with android-studio? Shall I clone all projects and build them?

Comment: This is a known problem with Android Studio - it chooses the source of the targetSdk value defined during the build, instead of the source of the platform the app is executing on. A workaround I've used in the past is to rebuild an app with the targetSdk set to the platform I know the app will be running on when I'm debugging it.

Comment: @adelphus, it won't help. There are different SDK and source revisions even for same API in the SDK manager. So even if I compile code using api23 for nexus5 with Android M I will get same problem.

Answer (score 0):

hexonxons,

Please refer to this post to build an SDK and import it into Android Studio. It should allow you to work with your updated api.

[AIDL Service and Android Open Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146370/aidl-service-and-android-open-source/37172620#37172620)